# ASP .NET MVC Core WEB API upload file showing error using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my client side html (I used ng file upload)

```
<button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFileToUrl($file)"
        ngf-max-size="100MB">
    <!--ngf-max-height="1000"-->
    Photo
</button>
```

Here is my client side js

```
$scope.uploadFileToUrl = function (file) {
        console.log(file) // Here console prints my file information 
        alert(file);
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('photo', file)

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:22475/api/FileUpload",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (message) {
                alert(message);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was error uploading files!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my server side

```
 private IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv ;

    public FileUploadController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.hostingEnv = env;
    }

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostProfilePicture(ICollection<IFormFile> files) // Here i get file count 0 on tool tip
{
    var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here i get file upload error i searched through net, all i got this code but its not working, can anyone help and point out what am i doing wrong here..

Comment: Hello, what error you seen when implementing it ?

Comment: Error in loading file on client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya i got my answer

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
    var v = Request.Form.Files[0];
    var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "uploads");


            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, v.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await v.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
    return null;
}
```

Take the file from request and upload it,Thanku

Answer (score 0):

You are calling action result name in URL is 'FileUpload' and Server side action result name is 'PostProfilePicture'. You need to maintain same name in both sides or you can add route name above httppost in server side code

```
[Route("api/FileUpload")]
[HttpPost]
```

Comment: It is my web api controller,, It is routing to this method but there is no file